# r ggplot stack identity

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hBhp.png)

i want to make this image..

my data is difficult to disclose so i make a arbitrary data..  TnT...

data
no total outcome
1   800    40
2   700    30
3   650    27
4   600    25
5   500    20

i tried..

ggplot(data, aes(x=no, y=total))+
`your text`geom_bar(stat="identity")
`your text`geom_bar(stat="identity")+
`your text`labs(x="No", y="Total")+
`your text`scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(900,100)) +
`your text`theme_minimal()

i want make

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A51P.png)

black bar is total, grey bar is outcome..

help me plz..TnT..

i write this topic using papago, so... sentence can be awkward...I ask for your understand.!!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For visualizing the chart that you want, you need to **pivot** your data.

You can pivot(make wide data long) with `reshape2::melt()`

```
df <- data.frame(
  no = 1:5,
  total = c(800,700,650,600,500),
  outcome = c(40,30,27,25,20)
)

require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df_long <- melt(df,
                id.vars='no',
                measure.vars=c('total','outcome'))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x=no, y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black','grey')) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,900,100))+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x='No', y='Total')
```

Note that `geom_bar(stat='identity')` is equal to `geom_col()`.

[image]

Comment: Omg I love it !!! Thank you soooo much ! I think this is right. I can’t execute this now but i will execute after 2 days ! 